# How to assign multiple users to an issue in gitlab

Tags: gitlab

This is how to assign multiple user to an issue:

`From an opened issue, expand the right sidebar, locate the assignees entry, and click on Edit. From the dropdown menu, select as many users as you want to assign the issue to. To remove an assignee, deselect them from the same dropdown menu.`

But it doesn't work for me when I click on a user it only assigns one user to the issue and there is no option to select more than one person!

How should I solve this problem?

Comment: I don't think this is a `git` question

Answer (score 0):

This [feature](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/issues/multiple_assignees_for_issues.html) is at the time of writing part of the [Premium](https://about.gitlab.com/pricing/premium/) and [Ultimate](https://about.gitlab.com/pricing/ultimate/) plans.